# How to access method GetEmployeeDetails() using iterator object

Tags: java

How can I call `getEmployeeDetails()` method using Iterator Object?

Java:

```java
import java.util. * ;

class Employee {
    String empName;
    int empId;
    String email;
    String gender;
    float salary;
    public void GetEmployeeDetails() {
        System.out.println(empName + " " + empId + "   " + email + "    " + gender + "    " + salary);
    }
    Employee(String empName, int empId, String email, String gender, float salary) {
        this.empName = empName;
        this.empId = empId;
        this.email = email;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.salary = salary;
    }
}

public class EmployeeDB {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Employee> list=new ArrayList<Employee>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System. in );
        System.out.println("Please Enter Number of Employee : ");
        int empcount = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < empcount; i++) {
            System.out.println("Please enter the Employee name :");
            String empName = sc.next();
            int empId = sc.nextInt();
            String email = sc.next();
            String gender = sc.next();
            float salary = sc.nextFloat();

            Employee emp = new Employee(empName, empId, email, gender, salary);
            list.add(emp);
            //list.add(emp);
        }
        Iterator itr = list.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            Employee i = (Employee) itr.next();
            System.out.println(i.empName);
        }
        Employee e = list.get(0);
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code will like bellow using `Iterator`

```
for (Iterator<Employee> it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
                it.next().GetEmployeeDetails();
            }
```

Here `it.next()` will return the employee object. Once you get the Employee object then you can call `GetEmployeeDetails()` method

You can use **for each** loop using bellow way:

```
for (Employee employee:list) {
            employee.GetEmployeeDetails();
        }
```

Using **lambda** expression, you can use bellow code:

```
list.forEach(employee -> employee.GetEmployeeDetails());
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change your method name from `GetEmployeeDetails()` to `getEmployeeDetails()`

Yo can call the method inside the loop by `i.getEmployeeDetails()` or for the Employee e by `e.getEmployeeDetails()`

```
Iterator itr = list.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    Employee i = (Employee) itr.next();
    i.getEmployeeDetails();
}
```

Comment: 'void' type not allowed here
          System.out.println(i.GetEmployeeDetails()); error occured

Comment: @SomeshGangwar You cannot pass the method to System.out.println() since it has a void return type. Just change your code to i.getEmployeeDetails(). Like the above code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this:

```
    Iterator<Employee> itr = list.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
  itr.next()
      .GetEmployeeDetails();
}
```